# BESX is not sending activation email

Tags: exchange-2010, blackberry, bes

On the same 2008 R2 server installed are an Exchange 2010 SP1 and a BESX. Installation of BESX completed without any problems and by following the instructions provided by RIM's site.  However whenever I log in as BESAdmin to the BSEX to try and activate a user, the activation email is not sent (and of course I am not getting any reply containing ETP.DAT from blackberry.net).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do to troubleshoot

1) Ensure you've made the appropriate firewall exceptions for TCP port 3101 that allow for traffic from your BESX server to go to RIM's servers and make sure your NAT rules are correct

2) Double check your SPAM filter to make sure emails from blackberry.net aren't being blocked. If they are then make sure you whitelist *blackberry.net

3) Try specifying the activation password instead of creating an activation e-mail. I've heard a few people that have issues with that functionality.